# How can I fix this textmate bundle load error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this error when running Android Studio and I do not know where the problem comes from and how to solve it. I have just started learning Android programming.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did tried already invalidate cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your Plugin Error Plugin "JetBrains Marketplace" is incompatible.

1. Download the textMate Bundles [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7221-textmate-bundles/versions).
2. Then extract the folder[bundles] and put it in the your Android
   Studio's plugin folder.
   For example:

   C:\Program
   Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\textmate\lib
3. Restart AndroidStudio

Comment: what is it anyway? mb just delete it?